# Returning to the start of a block of code

Tags: c++, loops, input, io

i am fairly new to c++ but im making a simple program, how would i return back to the start of the code while still making it remember what was inputted. for example say i pressed 1 than entered the name how would i go back to the main part where it asks you what you would like. Thanks for your time i appreciate it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char name[25];
char address[25];
char city[25];
char state[25];
char zip[25];
char phone[25];
 int reply;

cout <<"Press 1 to enter the name"<<endl; 
cout <<"Press 2 to enter the address"<<endl;
cout <<"Press 3 to enter the city"<<endl;
cout <<"Press 4 to enter the state"<<endl;
cout <<"Press 5 to enter the zip"<<endl;
cout <<"Press 6 to enter the phone"<<endl;
cin >>reply;
if (reply = 'one')
 { cout << " Enter the name" << endl;
  cin >> name;
   cin.ignore(80, '\n');}
else if (reply = 'two')
    {cout << " Enter the address" << endl;
    cin >> address;
     cin.ignore(80, '\n');}
else if (reply = 'three')
    {cout << " Enter the city" << endl;
   cin >> city;
    cin.ignore(80, '\n');}
else if (reply = 'four')
    {cout << " Enter the state" << endl;
    cin >> state;
    cin.ignore(80, '\n');}
else if (reply = 'five')
   { cout << " Enter the zip code " << endl;
     cin >> zip;
     cin.ignore(80, '\n');}
else if (reply = 'six')
   { cout << " Enter the phone number " << endl;
    cin >> phone;
     cin.ignore(80, '\n');}
else
{cout << " done";}





system ("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

}

Comment: You might want to read about loops.

Comment: = instead of == is most famous logic error of all time, check that first :)

Comment: I think before you add a loop to your code (that's the answer to your question) you should fix the problem that you already have. There is no point in adding more code to bad code. Check out LihO's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the condition here:

```
int reply;
cin >>reply;
if (reply = 'one')
    ...
```

was actually meant to be:

```
if (reply == 1)
```

literals placed between `'` `'` refer to single `char`, for strings you should use `"` `"` and for numerical literals, such as `int`, simply use numbers. You should also add an option that will stop the program:

```
cout << "Press 1 to enter the name" << endl; 
cout << "Press 2 to enter the address" << endl;
...
cout << "Press 0 to stop" << endl;                // <-- something like this
```

and wrap this piece of code with a loop. Also note that variables doesn't need to be declared at the beginning of function.

---

It could look the following way:

```
// print choices (press *** to ...)
int reply;
while (cin >> reply) {
    if (reply == 0)
        break;
    // some code...
    // print choices
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a loop! DO NOT BELIEVE THE LIES ABOUT GOTO AND LABEL! Using properly structured code you can always avoid using these maintenance nightmares. Consider the following:

```
bool doContinue = true;
int userNumber = 0;

while( doContinue )
{
    int temp = 0;

    cout << "What's your next favorite number?"
    cin >> temp;

    userNumber += temp;

    cout << "The sum of your favorite numbers is " << userNumber << endl;

    cout << "Continue?" << endl;
    cin >> temp;

    doContinue = temp != 0;
}
```

The idea is to have variables outside of the loop that hold the data that is gathered within the loop. This way you can repeat logic without having to repeat code. This example simply retrieves numbers from user input and sums them, but it shows the idea of basic looping. Also, looping must have an exit condition (in this case `doContinue == false`).